# Studying Programming Language Theory

Tags: reference-request, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, books

I have recently become extremely interested in understanding and proving aspects of (functional) programming languages.

However as I dive deeper in, things like $\lambda$ calculus, category theory, and denotational semantics are a little difficult to grok without proper explanation.

I read SICP (quite an enlightening book) but I'm looking to dive deeper into the theory of functional programming. Are there any books/blogs/sites/you-name-it that would discuss the theory of functional programming languages from the ground up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not easy to come by books that consider the denotational semantics of $\lambda$-calculus. One possibility is:

1. Roberto M. Amadio and Pierre-Louis Curien: [Domains and Lambda-Calculi](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1119342/)

Type-theoretic accounts are easier to get hold of:

1. Bob Harper, [Practical Foundations of Programming Languages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf) (there is also a [printed version](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item6886816/)).
2. Benjamin Pierce, [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/).
3. Frank Pfenning's course on [Computation and Deduction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/comp-ded/index.html), I think he also published a book with the same title.

Comment: I went with `Domains and Lambda-Calculi` as well as `Design Concepts in Programming Languages` (thick but worth it so far)

Answer (score 2):

**A new answer to an old question**. You might be interested in [Category Theory for Programmers](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/) by Bartosz Milewski. More generally, you can look at [Bartosz Milewski's Programming Cafe](http://bartoszmilewski.com) blog.

Answer (score -3):

These books have high ratings and come up on different scientific communities:

[Type Theory and Functional Programming by Simon Thompson.](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/)

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Comment: How do these books address *theory*? Why do you recommend them; have you read them?