# What should I read to understand semantics of programming languages?

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, semantics, books

I would like to have a good conceptual understanding of the semantics of programming languages: operational-, denotational-, axiomatic-, categorical-.

Is there a good (standard?) textbook for this?

Comment: A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Answer (score 5):

There are many depending on where you want to start and what exactly you want. 
Usually textbook start with giving semantics to the `While` or `IMP` language and then give references to semantics of lambda calculus (typed untyped) unless you are reading Gunter. I am listing down a few below that I have referenced a number of times:

1. Operational Denotational and Axiomatic:

   a. [Formal Semantics of Programming languages by
   Wynskell](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/denotational-semantics)

   b. [Programming Language Foundations by Stump](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Programming+Language+Foundations-p-9781118007471)

   c. [Theories of programming languages by Reynolds](http://www.cambridge.org/us/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521106979)
2. Denotational semantics:
   [Denotational Semantics by Stoy](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/denotational-semantics)
3. Denotational and Categorical semantics: [Semantics of Programming languages by Gunter](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/semantics-programming-languages)
4. Categorical semantics: [Category theory for computing science by Barr and Wells](http://emis.ams.org/journals/TAC/reprints/articles/22/tr22abs.html)
5. Mostly operational semantics (may be with types involved):

   a. [Types and Programming languages](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/types-and-programming-languages)

   b. [Semantics Enginnering with PLT redux](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/semantics-engineering-plt-redex)

See also [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/studying-programming-language-theory?rq=1) and [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/books-on-programming-language-semantics) on stackexchange.
and this [further reading section of wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)#Further_reading)

Comment: A list of titles is mostly useless; Google will do a better job on any given day. _Why_, specifically, do you recommend either book?

Comment: Agreed a list is mostly useless and each of of the books have some merits over the others depending on what the author is well versed with. Generally speaking, the answer to *why* a book is better than other mostly opinion based and not very objective due to the style of the writer, relatable examples for the reader etc. In my case, as i have mentioned in the answer, these are the ones that I have used and referenced and find them helpful in answering my doubts.